# php get value out of array with quotes

Tags: php, mysql, string, insert

Hello! I have a few SQL statements and I need to split them, I need the first image tag that occurs in the statement, I have the code for it to split it, but the problem being all of the different quotes. Is there a way to get it out out?

**Code I have now:**

```
$array = array('INSERT INTO ba793_content(`id`,`asset_id`,`title`,`alias`,`introtext`,`fulltext`,`state`,`catid`,`created`,`created_by`,`created_by_alias`,`modified`,`modified_by`,`checked_out`,`checked_out_time`,`publish_up`,`publish_down`,`images`,`urls`,`attribs`,`access`,`hits`,`metadata`) VALUES( 120333,139,'Champ Cars 2007','champ-cars-2007','<table style=width: 429px; height: 74px height=74 width=429 border=0><tbody><tr><td><img title=champcar_logo_2007.jpg style=width: 200px; height: 79px height=79 alt=champcar_logo_2007.jpg hspace=5 src=images/stories/Store/champcar_logo_2007.jpg width=200 align=left vspace=5 border=0 /></td><td><div align=justify>Exclusieve toegangskaarten alleen hier te koop! Wilt u tijdens het evenement op 2 september aanwezig zijn? kijk in mijn <a class=undefined href=index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=94&Itemid=>shop</a> en bestel snel!</div></td></tr></tbody></table><hr />','',0,8,'2007-08-10 16:21:48',367,'','2008-04-17 15:09:13',367,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2007-08-10 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','{"image_intro":"images\/headers\/zonderdeur.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/headers\/zonderdeur.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}','{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}','{"article_layout":"","show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","info_block_show_title":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_associations":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_page_title":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}',1,0,'{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}');,/* INSERT QUERY */INSERT INTO ba793_content(`id`,`asset_id`,`title`,`alias`,`introtext`,`fulltext`,`state`,`catid`,`created`,`created_by`,`created_by_alias`,`modified`,`modified_by`,`checked_out`,`checked_out_time`,`publish_up`,`publish_down`,`images`,`urls`,`attribs`,`access`,`hits`,`metadata`) VALUES( 120444,140,'Nieuwe helmen voor Nik en Koen','nieuwe-helmen-voor-nik-en-koen','<table border=0> <tbody> <tr> <td valign=top><img style=margin: 0px; width: 200px; height: 124px; border: 0px solid #000000; float: left; src=images/stories/Nieuws/helmen.jpg alt=helmen.jpg title=helmen.jpg height=124 width=200 /></td> <td valign=top>Speciaal uit Amerika zijn afgelopen winter twee nieuwe IRL Bell T6 Interceptors overgevlogen. Samen met de hoofdsponsor Eurogrip en Marcel Brouwers van Tjello Creations</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>','<p>is dit design tot stand gekomen en uiteindelijk super mooi gespoten op de helmen!<br /><br /></p>',1,8,'2008-04-17 15:08:48',367,'','2012-06-20 11:37:19',367,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2008-04-17 14:23:23','0000-00-00 00:00:00','{"image_intro":"images\/headers\/zonderdeur.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/headers\/zonderdeur.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}','{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}','{"article_layout":"","show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","info_block_show_title":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_associations":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_page_title":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}',1,2088,'{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}');');

foreach($array as $item) {

$split = preg_split('/src=/', $item);
$split = explode(' ', $split[1]);

echo $split[0] . "\n";
}
```

**I have a few statements in a array:**

```
INSERT INTO ba793_content(`id`,`asset_id`,`title`,`alias`,`introtext`,`fulltext`,`state`,`catid`,`created`,`created_by`,`created_by_alias`,`modified`,`modified_by`,`checked_out`,`checked_out_time`,`publish_up`,`publish_down`,`images`,`urls`,`attribs`,`access`,`hits`,`metadata`) VALUES( 120333,139,'Champ Cars 2007','champ-cars-2007','<table style=width: 429px; height: 74px height=74 width=429 border=0><tbody><tr><td><img title=champcar_logo_2007.jpg style=width: 200px; height: 79px height=79 alt=champcar_logo_2007.jpg hspace=5 src=images/stories/Store/champcar_logo_2007.jpg width=200 align=left vspace=5 border=0 /></td><td><div align=justify>Exclusieve toegangskaarten alleen hier te koop! Wilt u tijdens het evenement op 2 september aanwezig zijn? kijk in mijn <a class=undefined href=index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=94&Itemid=>shop</a> en bestel snel!</div></td></tr></tbody></table><hr />','',0,8,'2007-08-10 16:21:48',367,'','2008-04-17 15:09:13',367,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2007-08-10 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','{"image_intro":"images\/headers\/zonderdeur.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/headers\/zonderdeur.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}','{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}','{"article_layout":"","show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","info_block_show_title":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_associations":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_page_title":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}',1,0,'{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}');,/* INSERT QUERY */
INSERT INTO ba793_content(`id`,`asset_id`,`title`,`alias`,`introtext`,`fulltext`,`state`,`catid`,`created`,`created_by`,`created_by_alias`,`modified`,`modified_by`,`checked_out`,`checked_out_time`,`publish_up`,`publish_down`,`images`,`urls`,`attribs`,`access`,`hits`,`metadata`) VALUES( 120444,140,'Nieuwe helme en en','nieuwe-helmn','<table border=0> <tbody> <tr> <td valign=top><img style=margin: 0px; width: 200px; height: 124px; border: 0px solid #000000; float: left; src=images/stories/Nieuws/helmen.jpg alt=helmen.jpg title=helmen.jpg height=124 width=200 /></td> <td valign=top>Speciaal uit Amerika zijn afgelopen winter twee niIRL Bell T6 Interceptors overgevlogen. Samen met de hoofip en Mers van Tjeions</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>','<p>is dit design tot stand gekomen en uiteindelijk super mooi gespoten op de helmen!<br /><br /></p>',1,8,'2008-04-17 15:08:48',367,'','2012-06-20 11:37:19',367,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2008-04-17 14:23:23','0000-00-00 00:00:00','{"image_intro":"images\/headers\/zonderdeur.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"images\/headers\/zonderdeur.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}','{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}','{"article_layout":"","show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","info_block_show_title":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_associations":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_page_title":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}',1,2088,'{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}');
```

**I just want**

```
<img style=margin: 0px; width: 200px; height: 124px; border: 0px solid #000000; float: left; src=images/stories/Nieuws/helmen.jpg alt=helmen.jpg title=helmen.jpg height=124 width=200 />
```

I am getting now is errors because of the quotes that won't resemble a correct string, anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, and I'm surprised you're not getting syntax errors. You shouldn't use the same quotes to define the string and within the string. Either use double quotes to surround the string and single quotes within it, or single outside and double inside. Or escape the internal quotes.

Comment: Well, yes I know, but the problem is that my statement has json strings in it, which contain double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Parsing SQL is not trivial. (It's not hard either.) If this is a one-off job, you might get away with a few regex to pull out what you want. Otherwise you need to use a parser.

Regex `/<img[^>]+>/` will extract image tags. It will fail on a variety of edge cases so don't rely on this and verify the output. And you don't need PHP for this:

```
egrep -o '<img[^>]+>' < old_db.sql
```

This is really putting the cart before the horse.  Why not use the tool intended for the job: Mysql? Run the inserts, then query the data. Done. If you don't have mysql handy, try sqlite. It looks like it should be able to read your SQL.

Comment: Mmh, will I be able to get the image out of the column easier then? It is just a one-off job, I am importing a old database into a new one and need the images that are now in the text field inside the JSON, so thats why I am trying to get the images so I can add them into the JSON

Comment: I added a grep command that will extract all image tags. Does that work for you?